# How to manage job offers?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, career-switch

I am from lower middle class and money is a priority right now, recently I got an opportunities which offered me a good amount but I am not fully satisfied with the role since its on vendor payroll. Now, few days back I got an awesome offer from one of the dream company and I have my final round in next few days but the problem is I had to join the first offer because I cannot hold them back for too long and its been couple of days since I joined them.

What should I do? should I still go for the final interview? what if I clear the final round?

Comment: *I got an awesome offer from one of the dream company and I have my final round in next few days* - if you already have an offer, why do you need another interview?

Comment: @Brandin I got that offer when I got the job confirmation from the first company, today is my second day in the first company and my final interview round is on Tuesday for the second one.

Comment: So you don't have an offer yet from your dream company?

Comment: @Brandin no there is a final round next week. I have to somehow take leave for a day from my current(new) employer and then go for the final round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all in attending the final round of interviews. If you are given the offer and decide to take it, fine. Ultimately you have to look out for yourself. A quick change to another job once will not be an issue for you in the future. When this kind of behavior becomes a problem is when it happens over and over again. Based on your post, I don't think you will allow that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the final interview. If you clear the final round, and it is an awesome job at your dream company, then feel free to leave your current job (I know I would do so in that position).

I assume that you haven't been at your current company for very long at all, so you don't need to worry about getting a reference from them. If they ask for a specific reason for your leaving then saying that the role or the company was not a good fit for you should suffice.